# Python sonar doesn't collect tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have next in my config:

```
sonar.sources=dev
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=parts/jenkins-test/testreports/*.xml
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
```

I see test xml files which are junit format (jenkins also process them correctly).

When I run `sonar-runner` I see:

```
23:26:54.094 INFO  - Processing report '..././parts/jenkins-test/testreports/widget.tests.test_widget.TestLookup.xml'
23:26:54.094 INFO  - Parsing report '..././parts/jenkins-test/testreports/widget.tests.test_widget.TestLookup.xml'
2
```

But I don't see any test on sonar dashboard. I use sonar 4.3 version and runner 2.4 version.

**UPD**
If I run `sonar-runner` with `--debug` I see next in the log:

```
09:53:29.619 INFO  - Parsing report '..././parts/jenkins-test/testreports/md.authentication.tests.test_tokenauth.TestTokenAuthenticatorTestCase.xml'
09:53:29.620 DEBUG - Cannot find the resource for authentication.tests.test_tokenauth.TestTokenAuthenticatorTestCase, creating a virtual one
09:53:29.620 DEBUG - Saving test execution measures for file 'authentication.tests.test_tokenauth.TestTokenAuthenticatorTestCase' under resource 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@4336db7c[key=<null>,deprecatedKey=authentication.tests.test_tokenauth.TestTokenAuthenticatorTestCase,path=<null>,dir=<null>,filename=authentication.tests.test_tokenauth.TestTokenAuthenticatorTestCase,language=Python]'
```

Answer (score 1):

are these, authentication.tests, python packages? Is this on Unix?
see maybe related here: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Python-coverage-information-not-showing-up-in-Sonar-td5005729.html

Btw, I have the same issue, can display test coverage, but not unit tests stats...

Looking into PythonXunitSensor's code, looks like it is failing finding

authentication/tests/test_tokenauth.py from that SonarQube's step working directory, perhaps worth checking that path as well.

Cheers,
Rafael.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you for replying. The absolute project folder has Uppercase letters. But I don't want to proceed with this solution since I want 100% reproducible build on all capable machines